# Write punctuation after citation using superscript style with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, superscripts

I am using the superscript style in `biblatex` and it writes the citation number after the punctuation. How can I force to locate the punctuation (point or comma) before the citation number? Please see the example below.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[autocite=superscript]{biblatex}  
\addbibresource{test.bib}  

\begin{document}  
This citation number should be after the point.\autocite{A01}  
This citation number should be before the point \autocite{B02}.  
\end{document}
```

`test.bib`:

```
@book{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@book{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
```

As a return I get:

> This citation number should be after the point.<sup>1</sup>
> This citation number should be before the point.<sup>2</sup>

and I would like:

> This citation number should be after the point.<sup>1</sup>
> This citation number should be before the point<sup>2</sup>.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 3):

It is a feature of `\autocite` that it automatically moves punctuation around the citation.

If you don't want that, you can restate the `\autocite` definition without the punctuation moving argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[autocite=superscript]{biblatex}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{superscript}{\supercite}{\supercites}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
This citation number should be after the point.\autocite{sigfridsson}

This citation number should be before the point \autocite{worman}.
\end{document}
```

[image: This citation number should be after the point.1 This citation number should be before the point2.]

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. It is better to work with `\supercite` instead of `\autocite` in this case. Or it can be defined `\let\autocite=\supercite` in the preamble.